# maven META-INF services include still doesn't work

Tags: android, maven

Last days I've been trying to create a simple app for Android using Maven and Jersey to connect to my local RESTful service.

First, I created a local client with use of Maven and it worked. Then, I ported it to an Android device and here comes the thing: it throws exceptions.

First of all, there's this issue: https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/issues/detail?id=97 which was supposed to be fixed with 3.2.1 plugin version. However, I've updated my version to such and the problem still apprears. I tried many newer versions, but the same story there. Cleaning project, restarting IDE, uninstalling application - nothing helps. Had any of you a similar problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All files in META-INF-folders are ignored by [JavaResourceFilter](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/10e712627b86b2b0061dbd3a20f5f966b2cd7330/sdkmanager/libs/sdklib/src/com/android/sdklib/internal/build/JavaResourceFilter.java) which is used by [ApkBuilder](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/adt/idea/+/e54608a9498ced0348c84cf87f90dfebe907429a/android/common/src/org/jetbrains/android/compiler/tools/AndroidApkBuilder.java).

The only way to include these files into your apk is to put them there after packaging. so if maven doesn't do it you'll have to take care yourself.

I just did a little customization to build.xml in android-sdk and it works well.

See [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16898409/keep-meta-inf-services-files-in-apk).